# Can't import NLTK from within phps shell_exec

Tags: php, python, import, nltk, shell-exec

I have a python script being called form php's shell_exec command. All works well, except that it cannot import the NLTK corpora when called through shell_exec. The very same command is executed without problems however, whenever I call it directly from shell. I am using Debian 8.

This is my php-Code:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/python /var/www/include/sCrape.py -u '$my_url' ";
$response = shell_exec($cmd);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

This command works well when called directly (without sudo) from the root:

```
/usr/bin/python /var/www/include/sCrape.py -u '$my_url'
```

The error message from the python script I get (only when I call from PHP's shell_exec) is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/var/www/include/sCrape.py",
    line 221, in main() File "/var/www/include/sCrape.py", 
    line 211, in main sc = sCrapeClass() 
File "/var/www/include/sCrape.py", 
    line 61, in __init__ self._stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english') + list(punctuation)) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", 
    line 99, in __getattr__ self.__load() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", 
    line 64, in __load except LookupError: 
raise e LookupError:    **********************************************************************     Resource u'corpora/stopwords' not found. 
Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource: 
>>> nltk.download() Searched in: - '/var/www/nltk_data' -
'usr/share/nltk_data' - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data' -
'/usr/lib/nltk_data' - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data' **********************************************************************
```

Comment: Where did you "install" the NLTK data? According to [NLTK's Documentation](http://www.nltk.org/data.html) the path has to be `/usr/share/nltk_data` otherwise an environment variable has to be set.

Comment: @Liblor that has actually solved my problem. I will mark it as an answer should you want to post it as an answer :) Thank you very much for the help!!!