# Php cannot exec python script on - RPI3

Tags: php, python

I cannot at all execute a python script via php exec. This is my code

```html
<?php
$output = shell_exec("python /var/www/html/socket/power_on.py");

$output = shell_exec("sudo python /var/www/html/socket/power_on.py");

$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/socket/power_on.py");
echo $output;
?>
```

I've tried all of the above yet no luck the only command that seems to work that I've also tried is 'ls'
How to I give the user www-data access to sudo, as that may work. Since I've tried chmod 777 on the directory and file still no luck

Comment: `shell_exec()` was disabled ? https://www.plothost.com/kb/disable-dangerous-php-functions-web-hosting-server/

Comment: `echo($output);`  ?

Comment: If that was the case, why would the ls command work via shell_exec

Comment: Aw, sorry. didn't note that.

Comment: Seems duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721066/execute-python-in-a-php-script-using-shell-exec?lq=1

Comment: Well it would be a duplicate if that thread solved my question which it didn't

Comment: No output at all ? No errors ?

Comment: Check this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817074/calling-python-from-within-php-using-shell-exec

Comment: Yeah I get absolutely no output, okay I'll take a look

Comment: Yeah I looked at that thread before posting this, didn't help

Comment: Weird. You should at least get an error message. Did your tried to run the Python script from a shell ?

Comment: The shell script runs fine, i've tried running the shell to execute the python in a terminal window and works fine. Seems that the user www-data cannot run python commands or shell scripts that need sudo access