# How to call python from php on a remote server

Tags: php, python

I have an account on Gator.
I am trying to run a php script as follows

;`$command = escapeshellcmd('./simple.py 2>&1');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output`

I would like to get as output anything that the python script prints to screen,  but the output is empty no matter what I try (I use standard print in python

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817074/calling-python-from-within-php-using-shell-exec ? Might be stderr.

Comment: No.  Still no output. btw my python scipt writes to a file. I can read the file in php and return its content, so both scripts run. Just something really dumb about directing the output

Comment: it's just one of the hazards of PHP,  it does many dumb things. most of the standard functions are broken by design.

Answer (score 0):

Use my method as a reference.

I have this two files

> run.php
>
> mkdir.py

Here, I've created a html page which contains GO button. Whenever you press this button a new folder will be created in directory whose path you have mentioned.

> run.php

```
<html>
 <body>
  <head>
   <title>
     run
   </title>
  </head>

   <form method="post">

    <input type="submit" value="GO" name="GO">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['GO']))
    {
        shell_exec("python /var/www/html/lab/mkdir.py");
        echo"success";
    }
?>
```

> mkdir.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
import os    
os.makedirs("thisfolder");
```

Answer (score 0):

> `$command = escapeshellcmd('./simple.py 2>&1');`

`escapeshellcmd` is a form of surrender, it's php stupidity, it gets used as a DWIM band-aid when the programmer has lost control of the command-line.
It's breaking your stderr redirection.

Use `escapeshellarg` where you need to escape shell stuff.

`$command = escapeshellarg('./simple.py') . ' ' . '2>&1';`